# How to make a vibration delay for 1 or 2 seconds

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a phone call icon on my site, and this icon constantly vibrates, and this very much interferes with the site’s users. I want to saddle the vibration delay of the icon for 2 seconds. I tried to do like this - animation-delay: 1s. This did not help me. Tell me, how can I delay the animation by 2 seconds, but what would the animation loop be kept? Thank.

```css
.call_me_pls_from_mobile {
  animation: phone .1s ease-in-out infinite;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes phone {
 0%, 100% {
  transform: translateX(-21deg);
 }
 50% {
  transform: rotate(21deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<a class="call_me_pls_from_mobile" href="">
  <img src="https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/578/746/452/5bbc65ef3eb9c-thumbnail.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: `translateX(-21deg)` will do nothing but disable the `rotate(21deg)`. `deg` is not valid for a `translate` transform, and anyway it's not look like you trying to translate something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the animation to repeat indefinitely with a delay between repetitions, you need more keyframes.

This will approximate a one second animation with a two second pause:

```css
.call_me_pls_from_mobile {
  animation: phone 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes phone {

 0%, 4%, 8%, 12%, 16%, 20%, 24%, 28%, 32% {
    transform: rotate(-21deg);
  }
  2%, 6%, 10%, 14%, 18%, 22%, 26%, 30% {
    transform: rotate(21deg);
  }
  33%, 100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
 
}
```

```html
<a class="call_me_pls_from_mobile" href="">
  <img src="https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/578/746/452/5bbc65ef3eb9c-thumbnail.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sepcify the initial delay by adding `2s` between `ease-in-out` and `infinite`.

And  if you want to run the animation for a limited time, use `animation-iteration-count` property. Your delay is .1s and if you iterate it for 20 times, the animation will last for 2 seconds.

```css
.call_me_pls_from_mobile {
  animation: phone .1s ease-in-out 2s infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: 20;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes phone {
 0%, 100% {
  transform: translateX(-21deg);
 }
 50% {
  transform: rotate(21deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<a class="call_me_pls_from_mobile" href="">
  <img src="https://c7.hotpng.com/preview/578/746/452/5bbc65ef3eb9c-thumbnail.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```